# iOS UIWebView force image size objective c Xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, image, uiwebview

I have an incoming HTML that contains img tags.

I need to force the images to be max the size of the viewport: iPhone or iPad.
Currently the text fits the screen nicely, but the images overflow the screen size.
I can force to [_wvContent setScalesPageToFit:YES];, but then the text is too small.

Any way to make the images the screen size?

Couple of incoming examples:

```
<img alt="Comparison " src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-post-thumbnail/dsa_k4iI.jpg" class="wppt_float_left" title="Comparison  Photo" />

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-107864" alt="320d   Comparison " src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/590px4_2526_RT.jpg" width="590" height="329" title="20d   Comparison" />

<img alt="" src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-post-thumbnail/dsa_ka.jpg" class="wppt_float_left" title="2013 BMW 320i: Track Tested by Edmunds Photo" />

<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-107859" alt="" src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/201_-655x436.jpg" width="655" height="436" title="" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is construct an objective-c string containing javascript that will run inside the webview to change the image sizes to fit inside the `bounds` CGRect of the web view. Then tell the web view to execute this javascript by calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

Comment: I don't, but you can learn enough javascript to modify the images how you need by reading up a little at w3schools.com